# Are there any cryptographically secure PRNG libraries for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, random

Can anyone recommend a cryptographically-secure pseudo random number generator library for Delphi (Win32)?

Can be free or commercial, but will ideally be an active project. I'd like it to include source code.

Comment: Check out http://blog.synopse.info/post/AES-CSPRNG - it is a strong AES-256 based Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator, with higher security than the CryptoAPI black box (it uses CryptGenRandom only as entropy source).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Windows CryptoAPI:

```
uses Wcrypt2;

function GenerateRandom(Len: Cardinal): TBytes;
var
  hProv : HCRYPTPROV;
begin
  if not CryptAcquireContext(@hProv,
                             nil,
                             MS_ENHANCED_PROV,
                             PROV_RSA_FULL,
                             CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT) then
    CryptAcquireContext(@hProv,
                        nil,
                        MS_ENHANCED_PROV,
                        PROV_RSA_FULL,
                        CRYPT_NEWKEYSET + CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);

  if hProv > 0 then
  try
    SetLength(Result,Len);
    CryptGenRandom(hProv,Len,@Result[0]);
  finally
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv,0);
  end;
end;
```

Example of using the above code:

```
function BytesToHex(const Bytes: TBytes): string;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(Bytes)-1 do
    Result := Result + IntToHex(Bytes[i],2);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(BytesToHex(GenerateRandom(16)));
end;
```

Comment: The second CryptAcquireContext should be executed only if GetLastError = NTE_BAD_KEYSET. Else the code should raise exception (RaiseLastOSError) or return empty array. MSDN source:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379886(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The CryptGenRandom has known weaknesses. See http://eprint.iacr.org/2007/419.pdf Consider using it only as a source of entropy of a proven CSPRNG, e.g. as http://blog.synopse.info/post/AES-CSPRNG

Answer (score 6):

The [Delphi Encryption Compendium](https://github.com/decfpc/DelphiEncryptionCompendium) (which is famous-ish in the German speaking Delphi community, but nowhere else - presumably since it isn't officially promoted) contains a cryptographically secure [Yarrow RNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarrow_algorithm).

Just include the unit `DECRandom` (and maybe `DECUtils`) and use it like this (this example uses `IInteger` but that isn't mandatory):

```
function generateRandomNumber: IInteger; 
var 
  A: IInteger;  
begin 
  NRnd(A, 512);  // generate 512 Bit random number, 2^512 <= A < 2^513 
  Result := A;
end; 

initialization 
  // Method 1: uses system timer to initialize the RNG (seed)
  RandomSeed;   
  // Method 2: use own seed
  randomSeed(Data, SizeOf(Data));
```

Comment: That skimps over the random seed generation, which is a big problem in itself. One can use CryptoAPI (as shown in other answers) to generate seed and then DEC to generate the random.

Comment: @gabr: Seed generation is of course a problem - but dommer didn't ask for it. If you feed the Delphi PRNG with a good seed, it is still not considered cryptographically secure http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator...

Comment: Agree, but still it has to be pointed out - especially as your code shows two not-very-good examples of initializing the seed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ISAAC (Indirection, Shift, Accumulate, Add, and Count)](https://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html), a fast PRNG and also cryptographically secure. Probably ISAAC is as fast as the famous Mersenne Twister PRNG.

[Wolfgang Ehrhardt has done the Pascal/Delphi port](https://web.archive.org/web/20190729022124/http://www.wolfgang-ehrhardt.de/misc_en.html#prng) for ISAAC (free and source available). There is also a link to another Delphi port provided on the author's site, but I would go with the "Wolfgang Ehrhardt" version. I know his site for many years, and he has been updating with the Pascal/Delphi routines since then. Surely should be an expert on this!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the existing Win32 [`CryptGenRandom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379942%28VS.85%29.aspx)  API.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL would be a possibility.  Source is available although I am not aware if a Delphi version is available.  It includes a [cryptographically secure prng](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rand.html).  It is an active project, but it may be overkill for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was also going to suggest the [OpenSSL libraries](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rand.html). And you also get encryption, SSL, hashing etc included.
Indy has converted a lot of the headers and includes RAND_screen - but that can't/shouldn't be used, apparently, on programs without a UI. Unfortunately it misses out most of the RAND_* ones - but they're very easy to import and use. 
eg:

```
function RAND_load_file(const filename: PAnsiChar; max_bytes: longint): integer; cdecl; external 'libeay32.dll';
function RAND_bytes(buf: PByte; num: integer): integer; cdecl; external 'libeay32.dll';
function RAND_pseudo_bytes(buf: PByte; num: integer): integer; cdecl; external 'libeay32.dll';
```

then in the code:

```
  RAND_load_file(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('name-of-seed-file')), 512);
  //or
  //RAND_screen;
  ...
  ...
  const
    PKCS5_SALT_LEN = 8;
  var
    salt: TBytes;
  begin
    SetLength(salt, PKCS5_SALT_LEN);
    RAND_pseudo_bytes(@salt[0], PKCS5_SALT_LEN);
    ...
  end;
```

The same seed issues as discussed still apply, of course.