# rand() function in C is not random even when seeded

Tags: c, random

This is most likely a machine dependent issue but I can't figure out what could be wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  srand(time(NULL));
  int r1 = rand();
  int r2 = rand();
  printf("%d %d\n", r1, r2);
}
```

I compile the above piece of code using

```
gcc randd.c
```

Then running it a few times manually and the first numbers seem incredibly similar while the second ones seem random:

```
1025720610 1435057801
1025737417 1717533050
1025754224 2000008299
1025771031 134999901
1025787838 417475150
```

This first call to `rand()` seems strongly co-related to the time and is strictly increasing as time passes. Any ideas as to why this occurs or how to resolve it?

This happens on OSX 10.11

Comment: What system shows the problem? `printf("%d\n", rand());` might show the problem a bit more clearly. I'd expect to get the same output if the program is run twice within 1 second, but you're getting (slightly) different results each time. Please verify that the code you've shown us is *exactly* the code you've compiled and run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [srand(time(NULL)) generating similar results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668282/srandtimenull-generating-similar-results)

Comment: @KeithThompson I've posted a screenshot with the exact code and commands I'm performing

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Copy-and-paste your code into the question *as text*. The problem is based on the values returned by `rand()` we only need to see those values, which are integers. Something like this: `srand(time(NULL)); printf("RAND_MAX = %d, rand() = %d\n", RAND_MAX, rand());`. In your modified program, you're calling `rand()` twice. It's likely that the *first* value returned by `rand()` is the problem. And again, what system are you using?

Comment: @KeithThompson This is on OSX 10.11

Comment: It looks like value returned by the first call to `rand()` is strongly correlated to the seed somehow, and the second is not. Focus on that: `int r1 = rand(); int r2 = rand(); printf("%d %d\n", r2);`. Forget the floating-point stuff. Include the full text of the program and its output in your question. Also, tell us what OS you're using *in the question*. Assume that nobody will see these comments.

Comment: @KeithThompson Edited

Comment: @tuple_cat not a duplicate , you would expect the numbers to either be identical or completely different. not share a common initial sequence.

Comment: is this the exact code? E.g. you didn't use `random()` instead of `rand()` ?

Comment: @M.M Yes this is exact, I've copy-pasted it straight into the question. At this point this seems to be a deficiency in my c standard lib

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

1. `rand()` is quite bad, avoid it if possible.  In any good RNG the first values will be indistinguishable from random even when the seed is close (hamming distance).  In `rand` this is not the case.
2. If you must use rand then seed it, preferably with something higher entropy than time, and call `rand()` multiple times instead of reseeding-calling-reseeding.

For example of 2, consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int t=time(NULL);
  srand(t);

  for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    float r = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX);
    printf("%f\n", r);
  }
}
```

With the result:

```
0.460600
0.310486
0.339473
0.519799
0.258825
0.072276
0.749423
0.552250
0.665374
0.939103
```

It's still a bad RNG but at least the range is better when you allow it to use the internal state instead of giving it another similar seed.

Comment: Something like time xor pid, for example, is a *somewhat* better seed, but still very predictable. Really use `/dev/urandom` (or whatever the Windows equivalent is).

Comment: `rand()` is not inherently bad. Some implementations of `rand()` are bad.

Comment: @KeithThompson From a security standpoint, that `rand`'s specification is so broad and implementation is so unpredictable makes `rand` inherently bad.

Comment: @Schwern: Who said anything about "security standpoint"? There's absolutely nothing bad about `rand()`. There are just some applications for which it is suitable. And no, there's no need to somehow "avoid" `rand()`.

Comment: WRT avoiding: Using my, admittedly unexplained, definition of "good" I'd say I don't know if any good implementation of rand.  It isn't only about security but also period and number of possible random streams which is limited by the seed size.

Comment: @AnT it's hard to imagine an application for `rand()` that is suited by the output OP got

Comment: @M.M: Frankly, I don't see the problem. For a generator like `rand()` the only thing that's expected from it is a uniform coverage of the target range and absence of trivial patterns in each post-`srand` session. I don't see any problems with that in the OP's example.

Comment: I agree, there's nothing at all wrong with the user's `rand()`, he just doesn't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you should expect. There's no such thing as "a random number". There are only *sequences* of numbers with a random distribution. The `rand()` function generates such sequences, but you're not giving it a chance to, because you keep re-seeding it.  The first number generated by `rand()` may very well be just some function of the seed, or the seed itself. Some `rand()` functions might hash the seed to hide this, but that doesn't really make them any better, because the contract of `rand()` is to produce a random *sequence*.

If you need a sequence of random numbers that survives running multiple programs, you'll have to do something like (a) Write a program that calls `srand()` once, then calls `rand()` many times, and have your other programs ask for random numbers from that program over IPC; (b) Use something like `/dev/urandom`; (c) Use something like `random.org`.