# Why is srand(time(NULL)) working smoothly even though I repeatedly reset it?

Tags: c++, random, srand

I have a function that creates a vector of size N, and shuffles it:

```
void rand_vector_generator(int N) {
   srand(time(NULL));
   vector <int> perm(N);
   for (unsigned k=0; k<N; k++) {
      perm[k] = k;
   }
   random_shuffle(perm.begin(),perm.end());
}
```

I'm calling this from my main function with the loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    rand_vector_generator(10);
```

I expected this to not give me sufficient randomness in my shuffling because I'm calling `srand(time(NULL));` with every function call and the seed is not too different from successive call to call. My understanding is that I call `srand(time(NULL));` once and not multiple times so the seed doesn't "reset".

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668282/srandtimenull-generating-similar-results) somewhat affirms what I was expecting the result to be.

Instead, I get:

```
6 0 3 5 7 8 4 1 2 9 
0 8 6 4 2 3 7 9 1 5 
8 2 4 9 5 0 6 7 1 3 
0 6 1 8 7 4 5 2 3 9 
2 5 1 0 3 7 6 4 8 9 
4 5 3 0 1 7 2 9 6 8 
8 5 2 9 7 0 6 3 4 1 
8 4 9 3 1 5 7 0 6 2 
3 7 6 0 9 8 2 4 1 5 
8 5 2 3 7 4 6 9 1 0 
5 4 0 1 2 6 8 7 3 9 
2 5 7 9 6 0 4 3 1 8 
5 8 3 7 0 2 1 6 9 4 
7 4 9 5 1 8 2 3 0 6 
1 9 2 3 8 6 0 7 5 4 
0 6 4 3 1 2 9 7 8 5 
9 3 8 4 7 5 1 6 0 2 
1 9 6 5 3 0 2 4 8 7 
7 5 1 8 9 3 4 0 2 6 
2 9 6 5 4 0 3 7 8 1
```

These vectors seem pretty randomly shuffled to me. What am I missing? Does the `srand` call somehow exist on a different scope than the function call so it doesn't get reset every call? Or am I misunderstanding something more fundamental here?

Comment: `random_shuffle` doesn't necessarily call `rand`.

Comment: The standard has definitely had a few goes at `random_shuffle` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle is (3) the only one valid in C++17 and later?

Comment: How would you tell whether something has "sufficient randomness"? Did you run any statistical tests?

Comment: Calling `std::srand(std::time(0))` should simply give you the same seed within every second, it's still going to cause the random number generator to generate suitably random numbers.

Comment: Doesn't `std::random_shuffle` shuffles so each possible permutation has "equal" probability? You have to check how often each permutation occurs. Basically, for vector of two elements "1" and "2", "12" and "21" should appear 50% of the time each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to standard the use of `std::rand` in both `std::random_shuffle` and `std::shuffle` is *implementation-defined* (though it is often the case that an `std::rand` is used this is **not guaranteed**). Try it on another compiler? Another platform?

If you want to make *sure* the `std::rand` is used you should let your code use it explicitly (for example, using *lambda* expression):

```
random_shuffle(perm.begin(), perm.end(), []{return std::rand();});
```

On a somewhat unrelated note, the `time()`'s precision is **one whole second**, your code runs way faster than that (I would hope) so those multiple calls to `srand()` result in resetting to the same-ish *seed*

Comment: Std::rand does not have the correct signature to be the third argument of std::random_shuffle.

Comment: You are correct. I should have said "pseudo-code" as that was just an illustration of how it should be done, not the actual implementation.